# Detect double tap on ViewFlipper

Tags: android, double, android-fragments, android-viewpager, tap

I have made a nice ViewPager and now, I'd like to have a bottom menu bar appearing / disappearing as soon as the user double taps on the screen. I thought this would be very easy, but after reading a lot of forums and trying many potential solutions, I have to admit that I cannot achieve it. :-(

Would anyone be able to provide me a full code solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my base code :

```
public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity 
{
    static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
    CustomFragmentStatePagerAdapter fragment_pager_adapter;
    ViewPager view_pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragment_pager_adapter = new CustomFragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        view_pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        view_pager.setAdapter(fragment_pager_adapter);
    }

    public static class CustomFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
    public CustomFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
        Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment0();
                break;

            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;

            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            }

            return fragment;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by putting my GestureDetector inside every fragment of my ViewPager, instead of trying to put it in my main activity.

It seems that the ViewPager + GestureDetector = bad mix!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/938657/1354164) is what you are looking for.

If you use that as an example and override the onDoubleTap in the [GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html).

I know this isn't a full code example but it might help you further.

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not creating a DoubleTap catcher, but to make it work together with a ViewPager.